# Why can't I create a project in IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: project, ibm-watson

I click the "Create" button to create my first project in IBM Watson Studio and I become this message:

```
<html>
 <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
 <hr><center>nginx</center>
 </body>
 </html>
 <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

I deleted every other service except from IBM Watson Studio so as to have just one service in my Lite account, but it still doesn't work. Sorry for my english. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be just a temporary service outage.

Comment: Leave it some more time, maybe someone comes up with the best answer.

Comment: It may be a temporary service outage, but it also seems like a recurrent one, finding this thread helped me to mitigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your region to London. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I was in Paris and had set the location to Frankfurt. Setting it to London fixed it.